# Package version GUID in App-V 5.1

Tags: virtualization, sequencing, appv

I'm working with App-V 5.1. 
I'm interesting in what does "Package Version GUID" in the [Change History] tab mean? 
This value is different from "Package version GUID" in [Properties] tab. 
Also, I cannot find this value after adding package; publishing package in the appv xml manifest.
Does this tab [Change history] make any sence?

Answer (score 0):

[More details on the MSDN App-V Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e4b4d41-dd48-4be0-af34-f6ccbc867518/appv-package-guids?forum=mdopappv)

Comment: Seems this article almost about App-V 4.6. And there is also no answer, whether [Change history] tab make any sence.